# Array push not working inside promise then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All seems to works perfectly except i cant push my value to my array inside the promise all function ?? What am i doing wrong here ?

```
var reponses = [];

Object.values(thequestion.answers).forEach(item => {
  var mars = item.mars;

  var getFullName = FirebaseRef.child('/users/' + mars + '/fullName').once('value');
  var getAvatar = FirebaseRef.child('/users/' + mars + '/avatar').once('value');
  var getDescription = FirebaseRef.child('/users/' + mars + '/description').once('value');

  // console.log(queries);
  Promise.all([getFullName, getAvatar, getDescription]).then(answer => {
    var oneanswer = {
      answer: item.answer,
    };

    reponses.push(oneanswer);
  });
  console.log('oneanswer', reponses);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried debugger or adding a console.log() directly above the `.push()` to make sure your promise is entering the `.then`

Comment: yes it's entering.

Comment: When you call console log, `responses` hasn't been populated yet. If you call it just after `push` it should include the new value. Is this the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention that your `console.log` is outside of the **async** flow.

Therefore, you need to move it inside the "then" of the Promise.

```
var reponses = [];

Object.values(thequestion.answers).forEach(item => {
  var mars = item.mars;

  var getFullName = FirebaseRef.child('/users/' + mars + '/fullName').once('value');
  var getAvatar = FirebaseRef.child('/users/' + mars + '/avatar').once('value');
  var getDescription = FirebaseRef.child('/users/' + mars + '/description').once('value');

  // console.log(queries);
  Promise.all([getFullName, getAvatar, getDescription]).then(answer => {
    var oneanswer = {
      answer: item.answer,
    };

    reponses.push(oneanswer);
    console.log('oneanswer', reponses);
    // -------^
  });
});
```